# How to highlight the textbox red when a catch error occurs?

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

How to highlight the textbox red when a catch error occurs? The error that I am referring to is within a try and catch. I want to highlight the textboxes red where most likely there are erroneous entries. Example is when a user entered a wrong data type and then an error occurred I want those textboxes to be highlighted red.

Comment: Have you considered using validation controls?

Comment: What kind of text box?  Windows Forms?  Asp.net? Where is your error being trapped, during what event?  Why is this post tagged SQL?

Comment: Or the "ErrorProvider" which displays a warning icon next to a control (otherwise you would need richtext inputs to display the squiggly line)

Comment: Windows Form C#, the event is when I am inserting or updating data in SQL using C# Windows form.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using windows forms, it should be as simple as this:

```
try {
    //your exception here
} catch (Exception) {
    yourLabel.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

That will change the background color. Not sure if that is sufficient for "highlighting".